# Offline installation of libzmq3

Tags: 12.04, package-management, dpkg

I need to install the IRkernel on an off-line Ubuntu server at work. I followed these instructions (https://github.com/IRkernel/IRkernel). 
As part of the process I tried to install `libzmq3` but I didn't succeed since it depends on a number of other Ubuntu packages, amongst other a newer version of `libc6 (>= 2.17)`. The version of `libc6` already installed is `(2.15)`. When attempting to install `libc6 (2.19)` I get the following error message: `libc6 breaks locales (<<2.19). locales (version 2.13) is present and installed. Installing libc6 would break locales, and deconfiguration is not permitted.` (Note that the error message is not complete, since I typed it off the screen, because the server is offline). 
 I am on thin ice now, since I am not very experienced with Ubuntu. Can I solve the problem by installing an up-to-date version of `locals`? Suggestions very appreciated. 
Server info: Ubuntu 12.04 (precise) 64-bit, Kernel Linux 3.11.0-15-generic. Gnome 3.4.2. Processor: Intel Xeon(R) CPU E5-2680 v2 @ 2.80 GHz x 17

Comment: I just pulled the trigger and tried to install a newer version of `locales` (`locales_2.19-18_all.deb`) over the existing one (`locales_2.13+git...`). I got the following error message (typed off the off-line Ubuntu server): `dpkg: error processing ... trying to overwrite '/usr/sbin/validlocale' which is also in package libc-bin ... dpkg-deb (subprocess): subprocess data was killed by signal (Broken pipe) ... dpkg-deb: error: subprocess <decompress> returned error exit status 2`. I am not sure what to do next.